# Warrant AWS Python Cognito Error: User pool client ******** does not exist

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to use the Python library for using AWS Cognito called capless/warrant. Every time I try to instantiate, by using this function:

```
u = Cognito('your-user-pool-id','your-client-id')
```

(using my user-pool-id and my client-id, I have checked a ton!), I get this error:

```
An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the SignUp operation: User pool client ********** does not exist.
```

I have tried getting rid of everything in the user pool ID but "us-east-2", but this also doesn't work. Has anyone gotten this or know how to solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try with your region name.

```
u = Cognito('your-user-pool-id','your-client-id',user_pool_region='us-east-2')
```